# How do I scrape website data into excel BUT append the results to log

Tags: excel, logging, web-scraping

I have a device connected to local intranet, that will display various data values when requested.  It's a very simple format.  I can request the information in a web browser, or in Excel with a "get external data from web".

```
{
    "parameter 1": 1234,
    "parameter 2": -23,
    "parameter 3": 20818,
    ...etc
}
```

The problem is that it just displays the information requested, but no history. It just overwrites the new values over the old, and will only to it once per minute.
I would like to be able to use the parameters as column headers, and the values to keep appending to new rows every 1 to 10 seconds.

```
Timestamp  |  parameter 1  |  parameter 2  |  parameter 3
---------------------------------------------------------
  8:00:00  |      1234     |     -23       |    20818
  8:00:01  |      1235     |     -23       |    19800
  8:00:02  |      1245     |     -23       |    18550
```

Is there a way to do this in excel?

Comment: If you using powerquery then set up an append query to your historic table. Ensure you add columns to your query which output the parameter values. Otherwise can you use something like XMLHTTP requests and write to next available row?

Comment: What do you mean by append query and historic table?  When I do an "Append", it just combines two tables.

Comment: Yes. So, if you set up an Excel table as your historic table i.e. the one where you will keep all results over time. Then use powerquery > data > from table to add that table as Table1. Then do data from web to generate your second table which will have the new values each time. Then append new values table to the historic. Each time you refresh new values, I think, should be appended to the historic table.